# Multiplication two 32-bit SIGNED numbers with Addition and Shifting

Tags: assembly, bit-shift, multiplication, addition

I need to multiply two 32-bit SIGNED numbers using addition and shifting and get 64-bit number stored in memory locations `$0408-$040F` . This two numbers are stored in 8-bits memories.

```
 movb #$1F, $0400 ; the first number is $1F230001
 movb #$23, $0401
 movb #$00, $0402
 movb #$01, $0403
 movb #$F8, $0404 ; the second number is $F8012346
 movb #$01, $0405
 movb #$23, $0406
 movb #$46, $0407
```

I know how to multiply two 8-bits numbers with addition and shifting but I dont know how to go on with the others. I used an 16-bit Accumulator-D (accumulator-A 8bits MSB, accumulator-B 8bits LSB).

I am using CPU12: [Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/CPU12RM.pdf)

Can you help me please, guide me or show me how to do it please? Thank you, I spent much time on this but I don't know how to do it with 32-bits numbers.

Comment: It's the same algorithm, just with more bits.

Comment: Yes but how to do it when I have 4 8-bit memory locations, I can go through 8 bits (shifting, adding) but how to move to continue with next 8-bits?

Comment: Oh, this CPU has a 16-bit accumulator so you never needed to learn how to do 16-bit arithmetic using only 8-bit operations. (Hence you have no experience to generalize from.) Use the ADC instructions. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879819/add-numbers-in-avr-assembly/10894701#10894701) shows how.

Answer (score 3):

rewrite numbers as 8bit digits (base = 256) and solve multiplication algebraically:

```cpp
 (a0+(a1<<8)+(a2<<16)+(a3<<24))
*(b0+(b1<<8)+(b2<<16)+(b3<<24))
------------------------------------
=(a0·b0                        )<< 0
+(a0·b1 + a1·b0                )<< 8
+(a0·b2 + a1·b1 + a2·b0        )<<16
+(a0·b3 + a1·b2 + a2·b1 + a3·b0)<<24
+(        a1·b3 + a2·b2 + a3·b1)<<32
+(                a2·b3 + a3·b2)<<40
+(                        a3·b3)<<48
```

Now there are just `8-bit * 8-bit` multiply and `8/16` bit shift/add. Do not forget to carry on to higher digits (like `add,adc,adc,...`).

Hope I did not make a mistake

**PS.**

If you have 16 bit multiply can rewrite all process with base `65536` instead also can use Karatsuba algorithm for multiply for some speed up but be careful with the carry it needs more bits in such case.

Also I would do this on non signed numbers and add the sign evaluation later on

**Here some related QAs of mine:**

- [Fast bignum square computation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214) for karatsuba and other approaches
- [Building a logarithm function in C without using float type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214) for C++ 32 bit * 32 bit multiply
- [Cant make value propagate through carry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214) for 32 bit ALU operations in C++