# Can't make value propagate through carry

Tags: c++, math

Making a little C++ large precision class, and everything seems to work decent, but the add, if I add 0xffffffff and 0x04 together I get 0xffff0003 when I should get 0x0100000003.  Here is the function with the issue:

```
mpfl operator+(const mpfl &lhs, const mpfl &rhs)
{
    unsigned long i;
    mpfl ret(0);
    mpfl trhs(rhs);
    for (i = lhs.nbytes; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (
            (unsigned short)lhs.data[i].data + (unsigned short)trhs.data[i].data
            > (unsigned short)255
        ) {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                ret.data[i].carry = 1;
                ret.data[0].carry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ret.data[0].carry = 1;
            }
        }
        else
            ret.data[i].carry = 0;
        ret.data[i].data = lhs.data[i].data + trhs.data[i].data;
        if (i < lhs.nbytes)
        {
            if (ret.data[i].data == 255 && ret.data[i + 1].carry == 1)
                increment(&trhs, i + 1);
            ret.data[i].data += ret.data[i + 1].carry;
        }
        if (i == 0) break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Here are links to the full source (github made this easier since there is a lot of it)

- header: https://github.com/phyrrus9/mpfl/blob/master/mpfl.h
- class: https://github.com/phyrrus9/mpfl/blob/master/mpfl.cpp
- driver: https://github.com/phyrrus9/mpfl/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: When you set a carry bit (e.g. `ret.data[i].carry = 1;`) you're clearing bit 0 every time (`ret.data[0].carry = 0;`) instead of the bit for `i - 1`. Not sure if that's it but it "looks wrong" to me.

Comment: let me update that and tell you if it helps at all

Comment: no change. still incorrect. I believe its something to do in my increment function

Comment: @phyrrus9 Always strive for a ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  All your code should be in the question, not in a link with extra information.  I put the function you cited in the body of the question for you and fixed the links.  But really what's most desirable is a short and tailored single-file example which people can copy and paste into an IDE to reproduce your problem...with no extras, just the minimum to get the problem to happen.

Comment: @phyrrus9 I updated my ALU32 class code added rotations and pure C++ `mul/div` implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very messy to me. I did (long)num classes many times before (floating,fixed,uint,templated,...) so here are some hints:

1. **Try to setup ALU architecture similar to real HW implementation.**

   Most algorithms are written for such environment. It will clean and speed up your code. In some cases I use asm for this but if you want to be not **CPU** dependent you can use this class of mine

   **ALU source in C++:**

   ```cpp
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //--- ALU32 class 2.01 ------------------------------------------------------
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   #ifndef _ALU32_h
   #define _ALU32_h
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //#define _ALU32_no_asm
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   class ALU32
       {
   public:
       BYTE cy;
       ALU32() { cy=0; }
       void sar(DWORD &c); // msb -> [msb...lsb] -> cy     shift arithmetic right
       void shl(DWORD &c); // cy  <- [msb...lsb] <- 0      shift left
       void shr(DWORD &c); // 0   -> [msb...lsb] -> cy     shift right
       void rcl(DWORD &c); // cy  <- [msb...lsb] <- cy     shift through carry left
       void rcr(DWORD &c); // cy  -> [msb...lsb] -> cy     shift through carry lright
       void inc(DWORD &c);                                     
       void dec(DWORD &c);                                     
       void add(DWORD &c,DWORD a,DWORD b);                     
       void sub(DWORD &c,DWORD a,DWORD b);                     
       void adc(DWORD &c,DWORD a,DWORD b);                     
       void sbc(DWORD &c,DWORD a,DWORD b);                     
       void mul(DWORD &ch,DWORD &cl,DWORD a,DWORD b);          // (ch,cl) = a*b
       void div(DWORD &c,DWORD &d,DWORD ah,DWORD al,DWORD b);  // c = a/b d =a%b
       };
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::inc(DWORD &c) { if (c==0xFFFFFFFF) cy=1; else cy=0; c++; }
   void ALU32::dec(DWORD &c) { if (c==0x00000000) cy=1; else cy=0; c--; }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::sar(DWORD &c)
       {
       cy=c&1;
       c=((c>>1)&0x7FFFFFFF)|(c&0x80000000);
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::shl(DWORD &c)
       {
       cy=c>>31;
       c=(c<<1)&0xFFFFFFFE;
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::shr(DWORD &c)
       {
       cy=c&1;
       c=(c>>1)&0x7FFFFFFF;
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::rcl(DWORD &c)
       {
       DWORD cy0=cy;
       cy=c>>31;
       c=((c<<1)&0xFFFFFFFE)|cy0;
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::rcr(DWORD &c)
       {
       DWORD cy0=cy;
       cy=c&1;
       c=((c>>1)&0x7FFFFFFF)|(cy0<<31);
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::add(DWORD &c,DWORD a,DWORD b)
       {
       c=a+b;
       cy=DWORD(((a &1)+(b &1)   )>> 1);
       cy=DWORD(((a>>1)+(b>>1)+cy)>>31);
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::sub(DWORD &c,DWORD a,DWORD b)
       {
       c=a-b;
       if (a<b) cy=1; else cy=0;
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::adc(DWORD &c,DWORD a,DWORD b)
       {
       c=a+b+cy;
       cy=DWORD(((a &1)+(b &1)+cy)>> 1);
       cy=DWORD(((a>>1)+(b>>1)+cy)>>31);
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::sbc(DWORD &c,DWORD a,DWORD b)
       {
       c=a-b-cy;
       if (cy) { if (a<=b) cy=1; else cy=0; }
       else    { if (a< b) cy=1; else cy=0; }
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::mul(DWORD &ch,DWORD &cl,DWORD a,DWORD b)
       {
       #ifdef _ALU32_no_asm
       const int _h=1; // this is MSW,LSW order platform dependent So swap 0,1 if your platform is different
       const int _l=0;
       union _u
           {
           DWORD u32;
           WORD u16[2];
           } u;
       DWORD al,ah,bl,bh;
       DWORD c0,c1,c2;
       // separate 2^16 base digits
       u.u32=a; al=u.u16[_l]; ah=u.u16[_h];
       u.u32=b; bl=u.u16[_l]; bh=u.u16[_h];
       // multiplication (al+ah<<16)*(bl+bh<<16) = al*bl + al*bh<<16 + ah*bl<<16 + ah*bh<<32
       c0=(al*bl);
       add(c1,al*bh,ah*bl);
       c2=(ah*bh)+(cy<<16);
       // add subresults
       add(c0,c0,(c1<<16)&0xFFFF0000); c1=((c1>>16)&0x0000FFFF)+cy;
       add(c1,c1,c2);
       // construct result from (c3,c2,c1,c0)
       ch=c1;
       cl=c0;
       #else
       DWORD _a,_b,_cl,_ch;
       _a=a;
       _b=b;
       asm {
           mov eax,_a
           mov ebx,_b
           mul ebx     // H(edx),L(eax) = eax * ebx
           mov _cl,eax
           mov _ch,edx
           }
       cl=_cl;
       ch=_ch;
       #endif
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void ALU32::div(DWORD &c,DWORD &d,DWORD ah,DWORD al,DWORD b)
       {
       #ifdef _ALU32_no_asm
       DWORD ch,cl,bh,bl,h,l,mh,ml;
       int e;
       // edge cases
       if (!b ){ c=0xFFFFFFFF; d=0xFFFFFFFF; cy=1; return; }
       if (!ah){ c=al/b;       d=al%b;       cy=0; return; }
       // align a,b for binary long division m is the shifted mask of b lsb
       for (bl=b,bh=0,mh=0,ml=1;bh<0x80000000;)
           {
           e=0; if (ah>bh) e=+1;   // e = cmp a,b {-1,0,+1}
           else if (ah<bh) e=-1;
           else if (al>bl) e=+1;
           else if (al<bl) e=-1;
           if (e<=0) break;        // a<=b ?
           shl(bl); rcl(bh);       // b<<=1
           shl(ml); rcl(mh);       // m<<=1
           }
       // binary long division
       for (ch=0,cl=0;;)
           {
           sub(l,al,bl);           // a-b
           sbc(h,ah,bh);
           if (cy)                 // a<b ?
               {
               if (ml==1) break;
               shr(mh); rcr(ml);   // m>>=1
               shr(bh); rcr(bl);   // b>>=1
               continue;
               }
           al=l; ah=h;             // a>=b ?
           add(cl,cl,ml);          // c+=m
           adc(ch,ch,mh);
           }
       cy=0; c=cl; d=al;
       if ((ch)||(ah)) cy=1;       // overflow
       #else
       DWORD _al,_ah,_b,_c,_d;
       _al=al;
       _ah=ah;
       _b=b;
       asm {
           mov eax,_al
           mov edx,_ah
           mov ebx,_b
           div ebx
           mov _c,eax  // eax = H(edx),L(eax) / ebx
           mov _d,edx  // edx = H(edx),L(eax) % ebx
           }
       c=_c;
       d=_d;
       #endif
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   #endif
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

   - `mul` and `div` are switchable between fast **CPU** assembly and slower **C++** implementation with the `#define _ALU32_no_asm`
   - `DWORD` is 32 bit `unsigned int` and can be defined like  `typedef unsigned __int32 DWORD;`
2. **So now if you want to add two arrays (fixed size N)**

   It can be done like this:

   ```
   ALU32 alu;
   DWORD a[N],b[N],c[N]; // a[0] is LSB and a[N-1] is MSB

   alu.add(c[0],a[0],b[0]);
   for (int i=1;i<N;i++) alu.adc(c[i],a[i],b[i]);
   // here c[] = a[] + b[]
   ```

   it is a good idea to use the biggest base you can to improve speed. If you still need 8 bit **ALU** this can be also easily rewritten and even simplified due to direct access to carry. You can use 16 or 32 bit variables and extract `9th` bit as carry directly from sub-results (looks like you are doing it).
3. **Your problem (copied from comment)**

   My bet is that your problem is here:

   ```
   if (i<lhs.nbytes)
           {
           if (ret.data[i].data == 255 && ret.data[i + 1].carry == 1) increment(&trhs, i + 1);
           ret.data[i].data += ret.data[i + 1].carry;
           }
   ```

   carry should be applied always but the first time (you do it always but the last time). This also reveals other possibility how is your number stored?

   - `data[0]` is the **LSB** or **MSB** (low/most significant bit/byte...)?

   You have to start adding from lowest digits

   - **so either you just applying carry the other way around**
   - **or you are adding from highest to lowest digits**

   but booth are incorrect.

**PS.** in case you need `32` bit **ALU** style multiplication without **asm** in pure **C/C++** see this link (but after last update the code here already contains such `mul,div`):

- [Building a logarithm function in C without using float type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214)

Comment: Havnt checked this in a while, but yes, that is what I ended up doing.

Comment: Here is a question. This works perfect for DWORDS, but it wouldn't work for anything on larger integers (say 2048 bit numbers, like I need it to). You have solved my problem, but yet the code you gave me is neat, and does help none.

Comment: @phyrrus9 for bigger integers just change the 31 bit shifts to (n-1) where n is the bit count of used datatype and for inc change the max value ... (sorry I thought it was obvious)

Comment: I'd make `cy` determination in `add`/`adc` more like the one in `sub`/`sbc`: `cy = c < b ? 1 : 0` and `cy = (cy ? c<=b : c < b) ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: @greybeard result is the same. this class has been extensively tested so it should be bug-free.