# Karatsuba Multiplication Optimization

Tags: c, algorithm

I am currently working on an implementation of a recursive karatsuba multiplication method in C. I have all of the code working, and I have already optimized various aspects in my code (mostly memory). The only thing I have not touched are my addition and subtraction methods. I am currently just using the grade school method in base 2 ^ 32 (as is the rest of my code). Are there any faster algorithms for addition and subtraction that I could use?

Comment: No, that algorithm is already single-pass O(n). There's no faster algorithm. You might want to take advantage of hardware-flags and special instructions (carry: add adc sub sbc rsb).

Comment: So you touched getting rid of multiplication in favor of squaring using (a+b)² - (a-b)²?

Comment: I have the grade school multiplication method handling the small cases. What do you mean? @greybeard

Comment: In my general Karatsuba implementation I have separate methods for (x * y) and (x * x).  You can do a lot of further optimizing if you are squaring a number.

Comment: @Chaz look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214 for more ideas ...

Comment: That didn't even cross my mind. That's a great idea! Thanks!