# What are ways to do arithmetic with values whose corresponding binary-encoding is larger than hardware can support?

Tags: c, math, bit

If I wanted to do arithmetic with values greater than 2^32 and did not want to use long's, how would I do that?

I can think of a scheme where I implement numbers (to whatever number of bits I wish) by using multiple variables to implement a single number:

```
int upper32;  
int lower32;
```

The above 2 variables can represent a 2^64 bit value (if lower 32 overflows, I increment upper32 by one. This would require some overhead.

What are some better implementations?

Comment: the largest 32 bit integer is actually `(2^31)-1`

Comment: Since this is tagged [tag:c], try http://gmplib.org

Comment: Are you asking for libraries or algorithms for how you would implement this yourself?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `lower32` should actually be an unsigned int.

Comment: If you are going to use your mentioned method, it may be better to declare them as `int32_t` or `uint32_t` instead of `int` or `unsigned int`.

Comment: Merlin, I'm unaware of how solve this problem so both!

Comment: for operations like `+,-,++,--,` use carry ...  [32 bit ALU in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214) just get rid of the class structure and rewrite it to `C` format. now you can use this as a 32 bit module for any count of values ... if you need also higher operations like `*,/,...` then either implement them via polynomial operations with digit base insted of `x^i` or use any bigint library see [fast bignum sqr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214)

Comment: I've written a library to handle currency exactly not a double approximation. It has a sign portion and a nibble per digit. + - were easy, * a little harder and / % were pretty much brute force. The max dimensional of a number set at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with integers that are not larger than `2^64`, then you can use `long long` or `unsigned long long`, which are 64 bit integers.

If you want to do arithmetics with larger numbers, take a look at [gmp library](https://gmplib.org/), or write your own multiple precision arithmetic library (it's very simple).

Also, take a look at [this](http://en.literateprograms.org/Arbitrary-precision_integer_arithmetic_%28C%29)