# Binary arithmetic - addition with overflow

Tags: math, binary, addition

When I need to subtract 2 numbers (X-Y), I can take 2's complement of Y and add it to X. Let's say our system represents integers using a byte (8 bits).

```
X = 7 = 00000111
Y = 5 = 00000101
```

2's complement of 5

```
11111010 + 1 = 11111011
```

Adding those 2 =

```
 00000111
 11111011
__________
100000010
```

There is a carryover. How does one deal with this carryover?

If I am using 8 bits, that means I have a range of -128 to 127. So 7 and -5 and their sum do not fall outside that range. So this is not overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that depends on what you are trying to do

1. **if you are just computing simple/single `+/-` operations**

   then the overflow is usually ignored
2. **when you need to handle overflow/underflow**

   for example if you need to clamp the result for some reason (usually safety of the result range ...) then Carry flag of the **ALU** marks if the overflow underflow occur. After that you set the result as max positive or negative value depending on the inputs `sign,magnitude` and operation `(+,-)`. Aome platforms have instructions that do this automatically (saturated add,sub).

   Another reason is making `bigint` operations in that case carry is added as `+/-1` to higher operation (sign depends on the operation)... but the result itself stays as is (`add,adc,adc,adc,...`)
3. **on modern languages/platforms you do not have direct ALU flag register access anymore**

   sometimes you can tap into assembler but it can be slower in some cases then the computation itself. In that case use this approach [32bit ALU in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214) where `cy` is the carry flag

Answer (score 0):

Should have read my textbook again :)

In 2's complement arithmetic the carryover is thrown away, versus 1's complement arithmetic, where carryover is carried back and added to the result.

This video helped me understand - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKTsv6iVxV4