# Adding 0x10 to 0x7FF0 did not result in 0x8000, but instead got 0x7F00

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm currently learning x86 assembly language.

I have the following code

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
.STACK 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.CODE
    main PROC 
    MOV AX, 7FF0h
    ADD AL, 10h

invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Before I moved `10h` into `AL`, `AX` contain the value `0x7FF0`

[image]

After moving `10h` into `AL`, I was expecting the `AX` value to be `0x8000`, but instead, the value in `AX` was `0x7F00`.

[image]

How come adding `0x10` to `0xF0` in the  right-most byte (the least significant byte) did not carry over `1` into the second right-most byte? In other words, how come adding `0x10` to `0x7FF0` did not result in `0x8000`?

My guess is because when I added `0x10`, I added `0x10` to `AL` (`AL` at the time of addition contain `0xF0`), therefore adding `0x10` to `0xF0` result in `0x100`, but the carried over `1` is not preserved.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: you didnt add 0x10 to 0x7FF0 you added 0x10 to 0xF0.

Answer (score 7):

The code added 0x10 to AL, not to AX, resulting in AL = 0xF0 + 0x10 = 0x00. Change the code to add 0x10 to AX (instead of AL). You could also use | ADD AL,010H | ADC AH,000H | .

Comment: hi rcgldr, thanks for your answer. May I ask, is it right to say that regardless whether I'm adding to `AL, AH, AX, EAX` etc, if the result overflow, the overflow will be lost?

Comment: adding any register just affects that register (except adding 32-bit registers in 64-bit mode will clear the top 32 bits), so adding AL will only change the result in AL, the remaining bits will be unchanged

Comment: "the overflow will be lost" If you are referring to the overflow bit of the flags register, it is not lost.  It is always set based on the result of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this better like this (as the other answer suggest):

```
MOV AX, 7FF0h
ADD AX, 0010h
```

but what you wanted to achieve (I assume) is this:

```
MOV AX, 7FF0h
ADD AL, 10h
ADC AH, 00h ; propagate carry to higher BYTE
```

which is the base building stone for **bigint** math as you can add up together any number of bytes. First is **LSW** `add` and all the others up to **MSW** with `adc` for more info see related:

- [Cant make value propagate through carry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214)

Answer (score 1):

No the intel docs say that an add affects the CF so your carry out would "be  preserved" there.