# Binary addition carrying from left to right

Tags: c++, math, bit-manipulation, alu

How would you efficiently implement 64 bit binary addition carrying from left to right? Like flipping the bits then adding:

```
0101 + 1110 = BitReverse(1010 + 0111)
            = BitReverse(10001)
            = 10001
```

My current solution is to reverse the bit order of the inputs using delta swaps (and possibly a byteswap intrinsic), use normal addition, then reverse again, which is not particularly fast, but probably better than looping for 64-bit integers. (I haven't tested it but it would still be too slow.)

```
uint64_t addreverse(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    return BitReverse(BitReverse(a) + BitReverse(b));
}
```

This is quite slow, as the bits need to be reversed three times, requiring over 40 operations when using byteswap.

EDIT: I cannot store them reversed as I require regular addition as well.

Comment: 1 question: Why?

Comment: To manipulate the leading bits in various ways.

Comment: @me' This seems like a likely candidate for being an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). In what ways are you trying to manipulate the leading bits?

Comment: If you want performance then look which intrinsic your compiler provide. Or look for large integer library where someone might already have figured out how to do some operations efficiently.

Comment: Well, I already know how to manipulate the bits, I'm just looking to see if I can find a new method this way.

Comment: I require regular addition as well, so I can't just store them reversed. LUT could work, but I'll have to test it.

Comment: @me' I converted my comment into answer with working code and time measuremnts...

Comment: @me' I posted an addition, but leading bit manipulations can (mostly?) use their own log(bits) steps tricks that don't exactly do an addition and save some operations that way. And you could use `lzcnt`/`bsr` and `bzhi` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emulating a [Kogge-Stone adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kogge%E2%80%93Stone_adder), with the shift direction reversed, gives a nice algorithm,

```
uint64_t p = x ^ y;
uint64_t g = x & y;

g |= p & (g >> 1);
p &= p >> 1;

g |= p & (g >> 2);
p &= p >> 2;

g |= p & (g >> 4);
p &= p >> 4;

g |= p & (g >> 8);
p &= p >> 8;

g |= p & (g >> 16);
p &= p >> 16;

g |= p & (g >> 32);

uint64_t result = x ^ y ^ (g >> 1);
```

Comment: Nice (+1), but based on what I see with Compiler Explorer (Godbolt) this approach is really efficient only on ARM64 (20 instructions). For other platforms I looked at, this results in about 40 instructions with limited ILP, so possibly not much faster than OP's current solution?

Comment: @njuffa doesn't ARM have `rbit` though? that would make this much worse than triple-reverse on ARM, at least if that instruction is actually used

Comment: Good point. I know that ARM32 has `rbit`, but haven't checked whether ARM64 has it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **LUT** tables. Here small **C++ 32bit** (`DOWRD = unsigned __int32_t`) example:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// select fastest operation
#define BitReverse BitReverse1
#define AddReverse AddReverseKS
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD BitReverseSlow(DWORD x)   // Slow 1bit reversing
    {
    DWORD m0,m1,y;
    for (y=0,m0=1,m1=0x80000000;m0<m1;m0<<=1,m1>>=1)
        {
        if (DWORD(m0&x)) y|=m1;
        if (DWORD(m1&x)) y|=m0;
        }
    return y;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD BitReverse1(DWORD x)
    {
    x=((x<<16)&0xFFFF0000)|((x>>16)&0x0000FFFF);
    x=((x<< 8)&0xFF00FF00)|((x>> 8)&0x00FF00FF);
    x=((x<< 4)&0xF0F0F0F0)|((x>> 4)&0x0F0F0F0F);
    x=((x<< 2)&0xCCCCCCCC)|((x>> 2)&0x33333333);
    x=((x<< 1)&0xAAAAAAAA)|((x>> 1)&0x55555555);
    return x;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD BitReverse8(DWORD x)      // fast 8bit LUT reversing
    {
    DWORD y;
    BYTE *px=(BYTE*)&x;
    BYTE *py=(BYTE*)&y;
    static const BYTE BitReverse8_LUT[256]= // BitReverse8_LUT[x]=BitReverse(x) in 8bits
        {
        0x00,0x80,0x40,0xC0,0x20,0xA0,0x60,0xE0,0x10,0x90,0x50,0xD0,0x30,0xB0,0x70,0xF0,
        0x08,0x88,0x48,0xC8,0x28,0xA8,0x68,0xE8,0x18,0x98,0x58,0xD8,0x38,0xB8,0x78,0xF8,
        0x04,0x84,0x44,0xC4,0x24,0xA4,0x64,0xE4,0x14,0x94,0x54,0xD4,0x34,0xB4,0x74,0xF4,
        0x0C,0x8C,0x4C,0xCC,0x2C,0xAC,0x6C,0xEC,0x1C,0x9C,0x5C,0xDC,0x3C,0xBC,0x7C,0xFC,
        0x02,0x82,0x42,0xC2,0x22,0xA2,0x62,0xE2,0x12,0x92,0x52,0xD2,0x32,0xB2,0x72,0xF2,
        0x0A,0x8A,0x4A,0xCA,0x2A,0xAA,0x6A,0xEA,0x1A,0x9A,0x5A,0xDA,0x3A,0xBA,0x7A,0xFA,
        0x06,0x86,0x46,0xC6,0x26,0xA6,0x66,0xE6,0x16,0x96,0x56,0xD6,0x36,0xB6,0x76,0xF6,
        0x0E,0x8E,0x4E,0xCE,0x2E,0xAE,0x6E,0xEE,0x1E,0x9E,0x5E,0xDE,0x3E,0xBE,0x7E,0xFE,
        0x01,0x81,0x41,0xC1,0x21,0xA1,0x61,0xE1,0x11,0x91,0x51,0xD1,0x31,0xB1,0x71,0xF1,
        0x09,0x89,0x49,0xC9,0x29,0xA9,0x69,0xE9,0x19,0x99,0x59,0xD9,0x39,0xB9,0x79,0xF9,
        0x05,0x85,0x45,0xC5,0x25,0xA5,0x65,0xE5,0x15,0x95,0x55,0xD5,0x35,0xB5,0x75,0xF5,
        0x0D,0x8D,0x4D,0xCD,0x2D,0xAD,0x6D,0xED,0x1D,0x9D,0x5D,0xDD,0x3D,0xBD,0x7D,0xFD,
        0x03,0x83,0x43,0xC3,0x23,0xA3,0x63,0xE3,0x13,0x93,0x53,0xD3,0x33,0xB3,0x73,0xF3,
        0x0B,0x8B,0x4B,0xCB,0x2B,0xAB,0x6B,0xEB,0x1B,0x9B,0x5B,0xDB,0x3B,0xBB,0x7B,0xFB,
        0x07,0x87,0x47,0xC7,0x27,0xA7,0x67,0xE7,0x17,0x97,0x57,0xD7,0x37,0xB7,0x77,0xF7,
        0x0F,0x8F,0x4F,0xCF,0x2F,0xAF,0x6F,0xEF,0x1F,0x9F,0x5F,0xDF,0x3F,0xBF,0x7F,0xFF
        };
    py[0]=BitReverse8_LUT[px[3]];
    py[1]=BitReverse8_LUT[px[2]];
    py[2]=BitReverse8_LUT[px[1]];
    py[3]=BitReverse8_LUT[px[0]];
    return y;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD AddReverseSlow(DWORD x,DWORD y)
    {
    return BitReverse(BitReverse(x)+BitReverse(y));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD AddReverse4(DWORD x,DWORD y)
    {
    int i;
    DWORD z,cy0,cy,a;
    static const BYTE AddReverse4_LUT[16][16]=  // AddReverse4_LUT[x][y]=BitReverse(BitReverse(x<<1)+BitReverse(y<<1)) in 4bits
        {
        { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30 },
        { 2, 1, 6, 5, 10, 9, 14, 13, 18, 17, 22, 21, 26, 25, 30, 29 },
        { 4, 6, 2, 1, 12, 14, 10, 9, 20, 22, 18, 17, 28, 30, 26, 25 },
        { 6, 5, 1, 3, 14, 13, 9, 11, 22, 21, 17, 19, 30, 29, 25, 27 },
        { 8, 10, 12, 14, 4, 6, 2, 1, 24, 26, 28, 30, 20, 22, 18, 17 },
        { 10, 9, 14, 13, 6, 5, 1, 3, 26, 25, 30, 29, 22, 21, 17, 19 },
        { 12, 14, 10, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, 28, 30, 26, 25, 18, 17, 22, 21 },
        { 14, 13, 9, 11, 1, 3, 5, 7, 30, 29, 25, 27, 17, 19, 21, 23 },
        { 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 8, 10, 12, 14, 4, 6, 2, 1 },
        { 18, 17, 22, 21, 26, 25, 30, 29, 10, 9, 14, 13, 6, 5, 1, 3 },
        { 20, 22, 18, 17, 28, 30, 26, 25, 12, 14, 10, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5 },
        { 22, 21, 17, 19, 30, 29, 25, 27, 14, 13, 9, 11, 1, 3, 5, 7 },
        { 24, 26, 28, 30, 20, 22, 18, 17, 4, 6, 2, 1, 12, 14, 10, 9 },
        { 26, 25, 30, 29, 22, 21, 17, 19, 6, 5, 1, 3, 14, 13, 9, 11 },
        { 28, 30, 26, 25, 18, 17, 22, 21, 2, 1, 6, 5, 10, 9, 14, 13 },
        { 30, 29, 25, 27, 17, 19, 21, 23, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 }
        };
    for (cy0=0,z=0,i=28;i>=0;i-=4,cy0=cy)
        {
        a=AddReverse4_LUT[(x>>i)&15][(y>>i)&15]; cy=a&1; a>>=1; // add
        if (cy0){ a=AddReverse4_LUT[8][a]; cy|=a&1; a>>=1; }    // adc
        z|=a<<i;
        }
    return z;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WORD AddReverese8_LUT[256][256];    // LUT[x][y]=BitReverse(BitReverse(x<<1)+BitReverse(y<<1)) in 8bits
DWORD AddReverse8(DWORD x,DWORD y)
    {
    int i;
    DWORD z,cy0,cy,a;
    BYTE *px=(BYTE*)&x;
    BYTE *py=(BYTE*)&y;
    BYTE *pz=(BYTE*)&z;
    for (cy0=0,z=0,i=3;i>=0;i--,cy0=cy)
        {
        a=AddReverese8_LUT[px[i]][py[i]]; cy=a&1; a>>=1;            // add
        if (cy0){ a=AddReverese8_LUT[128][a]; cy|=a&1; a>>=1; }     // adc
        pz[i]=a;
        }
    return z;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD AddReverseKS(DWORD x,DWORD y) // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kogge–Stone_adder
    {                               // Adder from harold's answer ported to 32bit
    DWORD p=x^y;
    DWORD g=x&y;

    g|=p&(g>> 1); p&=p>> 1;
    g|=p&(g>> 2); p&=p>> 2;
    g|=p&(g>> 4); p&=p>> 4;
    g|=p&(g>> 8); p&=p>> 8;
    g|=p&(g>>16);

    return x^y^(g>>1);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `AddReverse8_LUT` is initialized like this:

```
for (DWORD x=0;x<256;x++)
 for (DWORD y=0;y<256;y++)
  AddReverse8_LUT[x][y]=BitReverse(BitReverse(x<<1)+BitReverse(y<<1));
```

Here measured times on mine setup:

```
 8M x BitReverseSlow [ 506.585 ms]
 8M x BitReverse1    [  59.769 ms]
 8M x BitReverse8    [  72.355 ms]
16M x AddReverseSlow [ 611.677 ms]
16M x AddReverse4    [ 491.546 ms]
16M x AddReverse8    [ 347.293 ms]
16M x AddReverseKS   [ 142.149 ms]
```

As you can see the bigger **LUT** the better speed at the cost of space. On top of that if the resolution is 8/16/32bit you can use BYTE access by pointer instead of slow bit shift/mask speeding up even more.

Just to be sure the Addition `LUT[][]` table is encoded such that the addition is shifted to left by 1 bit and the empty space is occupied by Carry flag for the next nibble ...

In the additions when I am doing the `adc` (incrementing by carry flag) the operand for `LUT` is `1` bit reversed in LUT bit resolution so

```
    1000bin =   8dec // 4 bits
10000000bin = 128dec // 8 bits
```

**To port this to 64 bit** just change `DWORD` to your datatype and change the bit masks and iterations count to match 64 bit ...

Anyway this reminds me at my old answer to:

- [Cant make value propagate through carry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214)

**However it looks like non LUT versions of `BitReverse` are faster**

After some digging it looks like LUT usage with temp variables force my compiler to compile my functions differently with great speed decrease (more tan twice). Once all functions are enforced to such calling api the LUT versions are sligthly faster:

```
 8M x BitReverseSlow [ 537.534 ms]
 8M x BitReverse1    [  99.804 ms] <- this is slowed down due to changing call style to the same as the BitReverse8
 8M x BitReverse8    [  80.725 ms]
```

so I suspect that for reasonably simple functions my compiler uses Assembly call style (not using heap/stack for operands and returning value).

**So the result is that:**

using `BitReverse1` is faster. Also harolds answer beats mine by far for the same reasons + it has less operations needed ...

However if you would hardwire this (**FPGA** or on die or using gates) I suspect the **LUT** versions of `BitReverse` will be faster (Although you can Hardwire bitreversal directly which is unbeatbale).

Comment: The performance is actually a bit slower for me, even with you LUT bit reverse. It might just be the hardware.

Comment: @me' anyway harolds answer beats mine by far  `16M times AddReverseKS [ 147.609 ms]`

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised I even got close to it, even with a fast bit reverse using a native bswap.

Comment: I was measuring 10 million and I copy and pasted your code, so that's not the reason. Also, it was a byteswap, with bitwise operations to reverse the bit order in a byte (15 bitwise operations and a byteswap to reverse bit order).

Comment: @me' I did some digging and found out the speed difference cause. I updated code, measurements and my finding into my answer. btw `BitReverse1` is what you use for bitreverse now ?

Comment: Yes, that seems right. I actually used a version of `x=((x>>16)&0x0000FFFF)|((x&0x0000FFFF)<<16)` (only one mask) that works well with the compiler, but your variation is close enough. Also, `AddReverseSlow` beat `AddReverse4` even with `BitReverse8`. Maybe it's because I had to call the functions through volatile function pointers to stop them from being optimised out.

Comment: @me' yep `volatile` makes fancy stuff especially on compilers like GCC (that is at least my experience as I am using GCC for MCU applications.... on x86 I am using Borland/Embarcadero instead as its much much better at least for my purposes). Btw make sure the LUT tables are compile time constructed ... took me a while to configure the code that compiler done it as such ... that was a huge speed difference.

Comment: The LUTs are compiler time, it's just the function call. The functions are compiled o=normally as well.

Comment: @me' I taught as much too but time measurements proved me wrong ... Anyway just in case if you are doing this on platform with slow memory access like ARM/SDcard then LUT will be slow

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it bit-wise and keep track of carry.  Something like:

```
uint64_t addreverse(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    uint64_t current_bit = 0x8000000000000000ull;
    unsigned int shift = 63;
    unsigned int carry = 0;
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    while (current_bit) {
        uint64_t bit_sum = ((a & current_bit) >> shift) + 
                                 ((b & current_bit) >> shift);
        sum += (((bit_sum & 1) + carry) << shift);
        carry = (bit_sum & 2) >> 1;
        current_bit >>= 1;
        --shift;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that would be particularly fast.

Comment: @me' Have you compiled it and looked at the byte-code? Done some performance metrics on this code?Also - how else do you propose to do it?  Your proposed way certainly doesn't work.  Think about different bit lengths - you solution falls apart quickly.

Comment: It compiles into a bunch of ANDs, shifts and adds, repeated 64 times that's about 800 operations.

Comment: With different bit lengths, couldn't I just use a different bit reversal method for the bit length?

Comment: @me' And how are you going to do that without any `&`s, `<<`s, `>>`s *etc*?

Comment: `x = ((x >>  1) & 0x5555555555555555ULL) | ((x & 0x5555555555555555ULL) <<  1);` and three similar operations, then bswap. 16 operations, done three times is 48. Then the add, that's 49.

Comment: Have fun debugging it.