# Inverse ModPow Usage

Tags: algorithm, math

I am trying to build [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof#Discrete_log_of_a_given_value) (ero-knowledge_proof: Discrete_log_of_a_given_value), but I don't understand how to implement `C = gr• (gx)-1 mod p` without actually calculating `x`. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: `g^x=y`, which is one of the values known to both parties.

Comment: @NicoSchertler right, but how do you get from that to `(g^x)^-1 mod p`

Comment: `(g^x)^-1` is the multiplicative inverse of `y`.

Comment: [Modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modular Inverse Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58618167/modular-inverse-calculation)