# Modulo operation by bit operation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, modulo

### Description

> Define the function `unsigned mod(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c)`; The function is to calculate and return the result of a*b%c. The range of test a, b, c is required to be greater than 0 and less than 2^31, and the program cannot use 64-bit integer (such as long long type or __int64) to solve.

Problem: a*b may overflow (beyond the representation range of the 32-bit unsigned int type). To solve this problem, the following algorithm can be used.
Suppose each binary bit of the unsigned variable b is xi (i=0,1, …, 31), i=0 is the lowest bit, i=31 is the highest bit, then
[image: image1]

and
[image: image2]

> In the above formula, the result of a*xi is either a or 0;
> *2 Operation can be achieved by shifting 1 bit to the left (integer less than 2^31 *2 The result must be less than 2^32, and overflow will not occur);
> The result of %c is less than c, and c is less than 2^31, and the sum of it and a will not overflow.
> Write a complete program and implement the above algorithm by iterative method.

### My Code

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned mod(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c) {
    unsigned sum = a * ((b >> 30) & 1);
    for (int i = 29; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum = (sum << 1) % c + a * ((b >> i) & 1);
    }
    return sum % c;
}

int main() {
    //to achieve the subject requirements
    unsigned a, b, c;
    printf("Input unsigned integer numbers a, b, c:\n");
    scanf("%u %u %u", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("%u*%u%%%u=%u\n", a, b, c, mod(a, b, c));

    //to verify output results
    unsigned long long ab, bb, cb;
    ab = a;
    bb = b;
    cb = c;
    printf("%llu*%llu%%%llu=%llu", ab, bb, cb, ab * bb % cb);
}
```

### Issues

When performing calculations with smaller numbers (such as 100*500/3), the result is correct. But when the number is close to the upper limit of the question (such as 2147483647*2147483647/3), you will get the wrong answer. I don't know why this is because I just program according to the formula given in the question, and I don't know the mathematical principle.

Comment: At what point exactly are intermediate results not as expected?

Comment: Drop all of these integer types and only use `uint64_t` from stdint.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Uduru already pointed out, `sum` may become larger than 2^31 and therefore, left shifting will result in an overflow.

To prevent this, remember the following: left shifting by 1 is the same as multiplying by 2. So, `(sum << 1) % c` is the same as `(sum * 2) % c`. Now, the rules for modulo state the following:

```
(a * b) mod c == ((a mod c) * (b mod c)) mod c.
```

So you might change the code to the following.

```
sum = ((sum % c) << 1) % c + a * ((b >> i) & 1);
```

Because `c` is guaranteed to be smaller than 2^31 (according to the quoted part), `sum % c` is also guaranteed to be smaller than 2^31.

Comment: Or use a unsigned long long integer or things like `uint64_t` in the function to get more space I guess LOL

Comment: as the OP states, using 64 bit integers is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

In `mod()`, you got `sum = (sum << 1) % c + a * ((b >> i) & 1);`, 
while the value of `sum` might be as large as `a` (a.k.a., a 32-bit unsigned integer).

When `sum` is larger than 2^31 (greater than `0b'1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`), 
**the left shift still will cause overflow**.

Comment: I understand, the overflow occurs at `sum = (sum << 1) % c + a * ((b >> i) & 1);`, when a and b is  2147483647 and (sum << 1) % c is larger than 1, overflow will occur. But then how to solve the problem?

Comment: @TPam for **modmul** on 32bit ALU use naive O(n^2) or Karatsuba for multiplication and then just do the modulo operation on 2x32bit result by binary division (shift and substract) or use newton rapshon ... see [ALU32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214) on how to do multiplication and division on half bitwidth arithmetics ...