# How to modulo this formula?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, module, combinatorics

I would like to write this formula in C++ language:

[image]

`(2<=n<=1e5)`, `(1<=k<=n)`, `(2<=M<=1e9)`.

I would like to do this without using special structures.
Unfortunately in this formula there are a lot of cases which effectively make modulation difficult. Example: `((n-k)!) mod M can be equal to 0`, or `((n-1)(n-2))/4` may not be an integer. I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

(n−1)!/(n−k)! can be handled by computing the product (n−k+1)…(n−1).

(n−1)! (n−1)(n−2)/4 can be handled by handling n ≤ 2 (0) and n ≥ 3
(3…(n−1) (n−1)(n−2)/2) separately.

Untested C++:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>

class Residue {
public:
  // Accept int64_t for convenience.
  explicit Residue(int64_t rep, int32_t modulus) : modulus_(modulus) {
    assert(modulus > 0);
    rep_ = rep % modulus;
    if (rep_ < 0)
      rep_ += modulus;
  }

  // Return int64_t for convenience.
  int64_t rep() const { return rep_; }
  int32_t modulus() const { return modulus_; }

private:
  int32_t rep_;
  int32_t modulus_;
};

Residue operator+(Residue a, Residue b) {
  assert(a.modulus() == b.modulus());
  return Residue(a.rep() + b.rep(), a.modulus());
}

Residue operator-(Residue a, Residue b) {
  assert(a.modulus() == b.modulus());
  return Residue(a.rep() - b.rep(), a.modulus());
}

Residue operator*(Residue a, Residue b) {
  assert(a.modulus() == b.modulus());
  return Residue(a.rep() * b.rep(), a.modulus());
}

Residue QuotientOfFactorialsMod(int32_t a, int32_t b, int32_t modulus) {
  assert(modulus > 0);
  assert(b >= 0);
  assert(a >= b);
  Residue result(1, modulus);
  // Don't initialize with b + 1 because it could overflow.
  for (int32_t i = b; i < a; i++) {
    result = result * Residue(i + 1, modulus);
  }
  return result;
}

Residue FactorialMod(int32_t a, int32_t modulus) {
  assert(modulus > 0);
  assert(a >= 0);
  return QuotientOfFactorialsMod(a, 0, modulus);
}

Residue Triangular(int32_t a, int32_t modulus) {
  assert(modulus > 0);
  return Residue((static_cast<int64_t>(a) + 1) * a / 2, modulus);
}

Residue F(int32_t n, int32_t k, int32_t m) {
  assert(n >= 2);
  assert(n <= 100000);
  assert(k >= 1);
  assert(k <= n);
  assert(m >= 2);
  assert(m <= 1000000000);
  Residue n_res(n, m);
  Residue n_minus_1(n - 1, m);
  Residue n_minus_2(n - 2, m);
  Residue k_res(k, m);
  Residue q = QuotientOfFactorialsMod(n - 1, n - k, m);
  return q * (k_res - n_res) * n_minus_1 +
         (FactorialMod(n - 1, m) - q) * k_res * n_minus_1 +
         (n > 2 ? QuotientOfFactorialsMod(n - 1, 2, m) *
                      (n_res * n_minus_1 + Triangular(n - 2, m))
                : Residue(1, m));
}
```

Comment: @user8593752 probably an overflow that you didn't expect somewhere. See above, maybe.

Comment: @user8593752 yep you need 64 bit integers for storing the result of multiplication ... or 2x32bit ... also this looks like too much code ... you can compute the factorials with for loops keeping each iteration modulo M to avoid problems with huge numbers (if you modulo just the result of factorial then you overflow verry soon if just few first iterations)... no need for classes and stuff ..

Answer (score 0):

[image: equation]

As mentioned in the other answer dividing factorials can be evaluated directly without division. Also you need 64bit arithmetics in order to store your subresults. And use modulo after each multiplication otherwise you would need very huge numbers which would take forever to compute.

Also you mention `((n-1)(n-2))/4` can be non just integer how to deal with that is questionable as we do not have any context to what you are doing. However you can move `/2` before brackets (apply it on `(n-1)!` so `modpi` without `2` beware not to divide the already modded factorial!!!) and then you have no remainder as the `(n-1)*(n-2)/4` become `(n-1)*(n-2)/2` and the `(n-1)*(n-2)` is always odd (divisible by 2). The only "problem" is when `n=2` as the `n*(n-1)/2` is `1` but the `/2` moved before bracket will round down the `(n-1)!` so you should handle it as special case by not moving the `/2` before brackets (not included in code below).

I see it like this:

```cpp
typedef unsigned __int64 u64;
u64 modpi(u64 x0,u64 x1,u64 p)  // ( x0*(x0+1)*(x0+2)*...*x1 ) mod p
    {
    u64 x,y;
    if (x0>x1){ x=x0; x0=x1; x1=x; }
    for (y=1,x=x0;x<=x1;x++){ y*=x; y%=p; }
    return y;
    }

void main()
    {
    u64 n=100,k=20,m=123456789,a,b,b2,c,y;
    
    a =modpi(n-k+1,n-1,m);      // (n-1)!/(n-k)!
    b =modpi(1,n-1,m);          // (n-1)! mod m
    b2=modpi(3,n-1,m);          // (n-1)!/2 mod m
    c =((n*(n-1)))%m;           // 2*( n*(n-1)/2 + (n-1)*(n-2)/4 ) mod m
    c+=(((n-1)*(n-2))/2)%m;
    
    y =(((a*(k-n))%m)*(n-1))%m; // ((n-1)!/(n-k)!)*(k-1)*(n-1) mod m
    y+=b;                       // (n-1)! mod m
    y-=(((a*k)%m)*(n-1))%m;     // ((n-1)!/(n-k)!)*k*(n-1) mod m
    y+=(b2*c)%m;                // (n-1)!*( n*(n-1)/2 + (n-1)*(n-2)/4 ) mod m
    
    // here y should hold your answer
    }
```

however be careful older compilers do not have full support of 64 bit integers and can produce wrong results or even does not compile. In such case use big integer lib or [compute using 2*32bit variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214) or look for 32 bit `modmul` implementation.

Answer (score -1):

The expression implies the use of a floating point type. Therefore, use the function [fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) to get the remainder of the division.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: no the expression does not imply floating point its still integer without remainders